# Programmatically get suggested values of autofill

Tags: javascript, html, input, autocomplete, autofill

Is there a way to get access to values suggested in an input with **autocomplete='on'** without manually clicking on it ?

```html
<input autocomplete name='email' />
```

I tried, with the help of javascript, to click/focus/faked a KeyboardEvent but nothing seems to work.
And even if I succeed to show the list of the different values, which I can't, is it possible to collect them after that ?

Thanks !

*first question on stackoverflow, have some mercy please*

Comment: Having access to the list would be a privacy vulnerability. But I don't believe it's achievable anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete area is a part of browser not the webpage. You cannot access its items. The only way is to create your own autocomplete module with `JS` and turn off the `autocomplete` attribute of input.